# Grouping via an element in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have this array

```
x=[{:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"ab", :price=>300, :quantity=>1},
   {:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abc",:price=>500, :quantity=>2},
   {:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"abcd",:price=>300,:quantity=>3},
   {:shipping_id=>4, :fsn=>"abx", :price=>600,:quantity=>1},
   {:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abb", :price=>400,:quantity=>1}]
```

I want to group it by unique shipping id, but in this case let us just group by shipping_id=2

So I do `x.select! {|y| y[:shipping_id]==2}` which gives me

```
[{:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"ab",:price=>300,:quantity=>1}, {:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"abcd",:price=>300,:quantity=>3}]
```

But the problem is I want my result in this form

```
x={:shipping_id=>[2,2],:fsn=>["ab","abcd"],:price=>[300,300],:quantity=>[1,3]}
```

What should I do? I can do this in a few lines, but is there any optimized way for it?

**UPDATE -:
Final working solution (My solution)-**

Controller

```
 new_params={}
 order_hash.each do |row|
        new_params=row.convert_to_params(new_params)
 end
 params.merge!(new_params)
```

Model

```
 def convert_to_params(new_params)
    item=self.instance_values.symbolize_keys
    item.each do |k, v|
      new_params[k].nil? ? new_params[k]=[v] : new_params[k].push(v)
    end
    return new_params
 end
```

This gave me my desired result

Comment: I disagree with this being too localized.  I don't think this question should have been closed.  There's a generic-enough grouping algorithm at the heart of the question that could be of use to others.

Comment: @JimStewart - I agree, I really don't think it was that generic a question. Anyways love the fact that my solution is pretty neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = x= [{:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"ab"}, 
{:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abc"}, {:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"abcd"}, 
{:shipping_id=>4, :fsn=>"abx"}, {:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abb"}]
@h = {}
arr.group_by {|x| x[:shipping_id]==2 }[true].inject({}) do |mem,i|
   i.each{|k,v| mem[k] =  [v] << mem[k] ; @h = mem}
end
p @h #=> {:shipping_id=>[2, 2], :fsn=>["abcd", "ab"]}
```

Comment: It more than helps....I quite like the solution. Would give it 2 votes if I could. :-)

Comment: @PratikBothra My pleasure! But `@h` has an important role here. I spent more time to get this work. atlast @h helped me out.

Comment: I finally didn't end up using your solution...But you should look at mine. Extremely simple.

Comment: @PratikBothra The way you presented,I provided the solution. And the result was tested,now that logic can be bring unto the something upper level. And Hope you should do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
ret = Hash[x.group_by {|e| e[:shipping_id]}.map {|e| [e.first, e.last.map {|t| t[:fsn]}]}]
```

and then, if you need only the ones for shipping_id = 2

```
> ret[2]
=> ["ab", "abcd"]
```

Comment: Nice try, but I want the shipping_id too in an array even though they are identical. And this looks quite long.

Comment: So I get something like this {2=>["ab", "abcd"], 3=>["abc", "abb"], 4=>["abx"]}. Let the group_by be for now. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @PratikBothra needing a list of duplicate shipping IDs is a very strange requirement. If you add some information about the domain, you might get some suggestions about how to better structure the solution.

Comment: Instead of writing multiple new API's, I am trying to make adjustment my values to fit that API. These API's would take input from a form where they could be may rows. So basically the tradition params is of the form params={fsn=>[],shiping_id=>[]}....That's all

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

```
>> z = x.group_by {|y| y[:shipping_id] }
#=> {2=>[{:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"ab"}, {:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"abcd"}], 3=>[{:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abc"}, {:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abb"}], 4=>[{:shipping_id=>4, :fsn=>"abx"}]}

>> Hash[z.map {|k, v| Array[[k]*v.count, v] }]
#=> {[2, 2]=>[{:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"ab"}, {:shipping_id=>2, :fsn=>"abcd"}], [3, 3]=>[{:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abc"}, {:shipping_id=>3, :fsn=>"abb"}], [4]=>[{:shipping_id=>4, :fsn=>"abx"}]}
```

Not exactly what you need, still leave it here in case you find it useful somehow.