# Looping over attributes of object of a Non-Active-Record-Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The simple way to loop over all attributes of an object when using Active Record is

```
order_item_object.attributes.each do |key,value|
....
end
```

But this doesn't work, when we are not using Active Record. How can I iterate over all the attributes of an object then?

For eg -: 
I have a model in Rails which does not use active record.
The object from model order_item can be used in the controller like  order_item_object.product_id, order_item_object.quantity, order_item_object.quoted_price. But when I try to `order_item_object.attributes.each do |k,v|` ...., I get `undefined method "attributes" for #<Order:0x00000005aa81b0>`

How should I go about this?

Comment: means class variables, instance variables or what?

Comment: These are the attributes (attr_accessor) defined in the model, that I want to loop over for an object. I think I am using it in the controller which is causing the problem?

Comment: you have a typo, actually. there's no double 'r' in `attributes`.

Comment: ok, context needed now. what is `order_item_object`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing the Accessors in a Ruby Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676200/listing-the-accessors-in-a-ruby-class)

Comment: Well you can just provide a hash of attributes in your model. or look at basing it off ActiveModel if you want ActiveRecord type functionality with out using the DB

Comment: @Doon - I'm gonna go with the hash of attributes saved in the controller itself. Just find it weird, that I can't iterate over all attributes of the object directly in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way I found

```
item=self.instance_values.symbolize_keys
item.each do |k,v|
  ...
  ..
end
```

There is a code to show it's usage here (look at the update in the question itself) - [Grouping via an element in hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194778/grouping-via-an-element-in-hash)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
class Parent
  def self.attr_accessor(*vars)
    @attributes ||= []
    @attributes.concat vars
    super(*vars)
  end

  def self.attributes
    @attributes
  end

  def attributes
    self.class.attributes
  end
end

class ChildClass < Parent
  attr_accessor :id, :title, :body
end

p ChildClass.new.attributes.inspect #=> [:id, :title, :body]
```

Comment: Thanks for this—it works in the use case where the attribute may not have a value yet.

Answer (score 3):

`attr_accessor` is simply a macro that creates some methods to set an instance variable.  SO perhaps what you want is the `instance_variables` method, which returns an array of instance variables that you can iterate through

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  attr_accessor :baz
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = 123
foo.baz
foo.instance_variables.each do |ivar_name|
  ivar_value = foo.instance_variable_get ivar_name
  # do something with ivar_name and ivar_value
end
```

---

But I wouldn't really recommend this. ActiveRecord keeps model data separate for a reason.  Your instance may have lots of uses for instance variables.  For instance, perhaps you want to track if the record is saved yet or not.  This may be kept in `@saved` variable, which reflects the state of the instance but not the data of the model.

Perhaps you want to keep a hash of attributes instead?

Comment: Instance variable definitely won't work.....This app is not connected to the db. More of a front end job. I think I am gonna go with the hash of attributes permanently saved. Just wanted to confirm whether I was missing something obvious or not.

Comment: Instance variables have nothing to do with the DB.  But how you traverse the data in your model obviously has everything to do with how the data in your model is sotred.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string representations of your instance variables, you can do:

```
self.instance_values.keys.each do |k|
 ..
end
```

That should loop over all the keys (instance variable names as strings) that are defined for your class.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes you are referencing is an instance variable on ActiveRecord models which returns a hash of the models db attributes.

A non-ActiveRecord model won't have the attributes method you are calling unless you defined it explicitly. All objects have a method called instance_variables which you can use to get a list of attribute names and then reflectively find the attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

A not very elegant way of doing it:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :firstname,:lastname
  def initialize(fn,ln); @firstname = fn; @lastname = ln; end
end

o = Test.new("Fernando", "Mendez")
o.instance_variables.each {|e| p o.send e.to_s.sub("@","").to_sym}
output:
"Fernando"
"Mendez"
```

If you want to keep a track of the key-value pair:

```
r = o.instance_variables.map {|e| Hash[e,(o.send e.to_s.sub("@","").to_sym)]}

#[{:@firstname=>"Fernando"}, {:@lastname=>"Mendez"}]
```

Comment: Thanks...Appreciate the effort, but as you said it isn't elegant.